# Number Theory Problem (j-qk>0)

Tags: number-theory

I'm beginning Number Theory by George Andrews and just learned mathematical induction, The Basis Representation Theorem, and Euclid's Division Lemma. I need help with this question.

Without using Euclid's Division Theorem, prove that for each pair of integers, j and k(k>0) that there is a integer (q) that j-qk >0. I was thinking of using the BRT, but couldn't get anywhere. Help.

Comment: j - qk > 0 if and only if j > kq.  If j >0 set q = 0.  If j = 0 set k = -1.  If j < 0 set q to j-1.

Answer (score 1):

The field $\Bbb R$ with the usual operations and order has the Archimedean property:

> If $x\in\Bbb R$ and $y>0$ then there exists $n\in \Bbb N$ such that
>   $ny>x$.

If you are allowed to use this, the proof should be straightforward.

$\Bbb Q$ has also this property.

Comment: Considering the context (elementary number theory, just after induction has been presented), this is probably not the type of proof that the author intended.

Comment: Nor sure how you can have the basis representation theorem without archimedian principal at least assummed.

Comment: To be honest I don't have the slightest idea what type of proof the author had in mind.  It's a perfect testing of comprehension for the archimedian principal.  Otherwise it just seems like pointless hacking as in my rather silly but valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad sword cutting everything to bits approach.

If $j > 0$ then $j > 0*k $.  Let $q=0$

If $j =0$ then $j > -k $.  Let $q=-1$.

If $j < 0$ then $j > (j -1) \ge k (j-1) $.  Let $q = j-1$.